# Program to decorate Windows taskbar buttons to easily identify at a glance

Tags: windows, gui, productivity

## Problem to solve

[image]

I often have multiple Chrome windows open, each one containing tabs with a certain purpose/function.

- Red = tabs for my open Google docs
- Blue = tabs containing my research items (Google searches, SO, dev blogs)
- Green = tabs containing my work administrative app (trello, toggl, slack)

My problem is, I easily lose track of which task is which. I'd like to "just know" which task I want without the slow-down of Aero Peek, or click each task until I find it.

## App Description

Does anyone know of an app that can do something to make it easier to identify my taskbar button at a glance like the screenshot I've mocked up.

## Caveats

- Since, Chrome is my primary use case, an app that targets Chrome directly would be acceptable.

## Now that I think of it

- Perhaps this is a problem best solved by DisplayFusion (which I already have a license for). That said, I'm open to suggestions of other apps.

Comment: SO meta-ish question. Would it be cheating if I were to offer a reputation bounty on this question with the intention of enticing someone to write an app that meets the specifications of said app that I have postulated in this question? i.e. Will someone code for reputation ?